# DataTables does not save state of date range search

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using data tables to display a list of events of different types. Besides the default global text search I need to 
1. filter list by event type
2. filter list by date range (show only today -> infinity)
3. Save the state of the table for the the current session.

The state saves as expected **except** for the date range search which is always reset. Am I missing something or custom search functions are out of the scope of state saving? Here's the relevant code in jQuery:

Fist I add my own search function through the provided method. This works except it's state is not saved

```
// Extend search() 
var threshold_timestamp = xxxxxxxxxxxx // set for beginning of today)
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var timestamp = parseInt(data[1]); // event date timestamp
        if (timestamp > threshold_timestamp) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Then I add a listeners for the `select` used to switch between the event type options ('','Event','Sports','Dance'...) and the button user to turn on/off the date range filter

```
$('#filter-by-type').on('change', function() {
    table.columns(0).search( $(this).val() ).draw();
}); 

$('#dt-history').on('click', function() {
    // Logic to toggle threshold_timestamp between 0 or value
    table.draw();
});
```

Then I call DataTables

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "datasource.json",
    stateSave : true,
    stateDuration: -1,
    columns: [
        { data: "type"}, //str as 'Sport','Dance'  
        { data: "date"}  // int as 1528572000      
    ]
});
```

I managed to scratch my head sideways and "save the date search" using localstorage but that is a hack. On page load I trigger a button click to execute the search so initially the tables seems empty, the "No data available in table" message appears and then the filtered results display. As a second hack I will suppress that message so when there will really be no data... there will be no message :(